# Access Javascript array in Spring mvc controller

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

Right now I am sending some parameters through URL to the controller in spring mvc project. If the parameters are too long the url is more than 2083 characters which IE do not accept more than 2083 characters in a url.So I am thinking to access the front end JavaScript array in the backend controller. How is it possible or any other better alternative suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible "to access the front end JavaScript array in the backend controller". The JavaScript array (and the logic around it) is in the browser, and your Java backend is on your server. The communication path are the URLs.

You're probably currently sending your parameters with GET requests. You have to switch to POST requests, then you'll be able to send much much more than 2000 characters.

See Spring docs section "`Mapping Requests With @RequestMapping`", depending on the Spring version you use, e.g.:

- [Spring 3.1.x](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping)
- [Spring 4.3.x](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping)

Comment: I see I am doing a post in the console.

Comment: You need to provide more details on the nature of your client side, e.g. how do you send those requests, what library or framework you use, maybe an (anonymized) example, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `POST` instead of `GET` while making the call to the server side. And have your data in the payload of the request.

Comment: I am doing a post only. Can you please provide an example??

Comment: When you say "sending some parameters through the URL", it implies that you are using GET not POST.. it may be that on the controller side you are just routing your GET to POST, but at the browsers side, you are requesting via GET